# FITS Export with custom Metadata

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fits

does anybody has experience in exporting data as a `FITS` file with custom Metadata (`FITS` header) information? So far I was only able to generate `FITS` files with the standard Mathematica `FITS` header template. The documentation gives no hint on whether custom Metadata export is supported and how it might be done.

The following suggestions from comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica do not work:

```
header=Import[<some FITS file>, "Metadata"]; 
Export<"test.fits",data ,"Metadata"->header]
```

or

```
Export["test.fits",{"Data"->data,"Metadata"->header}]
```

What is the proper way to export my own Metadata to a `FITS` file ?

Cheers,

Markus

Update: response from Wolfram Support:
"Mathematica does not yet support *Export* of metadata for FITS file.  The
example are referring to importing of this data.  We do plan to support
this in the future..."
"There are also plans to include binary tables into FITS import
functionality."

I will try to come up with some workaround.

Comment: Hi Markus. Welcome to stackoverflow.  I've edited your question to markup your code. (And sorry I don't know anything about FITS files...)

Comment: @Markus The error reporting in the Export[] command is very deficient. I found it just fails silently sometimes... so debugging is very difficult.

Comment: Tried all kinds of tricks. Nothing works. ExportString doesn't seem to work for FITS either. Perhaps time for a bug report?

Comment: @Sjoerd I did the same here. Import works pretty well, but Export[] seems to be able to deal with the images only. Seems more a non-implemented feature than a bug.

Comment: @belisarius Indeed. I tried "Image" and that works and mma generates "Metadata" itself which you can read back but not set. "Author", "Comments" when exported yield None and {} when Imported.

Comment: @rcollyer True. Somewhere in mathgroups I found `ConversionOptions->{"Verbose"->True}` did this in v5.2

Comment: @belisarius, As far as poor error reporting, I've found that with png files, mma offloads the processing to an external program and you have to wait for it to be finished before you have a real picture. Something similar most probably happens with other formats, too.

Comment: @belisarius, sorry. I deleted the comment on version as the docs for v.7 and v.8 are identical.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes. The program here is `fits.exe`. I disassembled it a little to see if something comes out quickly, to no avail

Comment: @belisarius I sent a bug report to Wolfram.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/FITS.html) for v.7 and v.8, there is a couple of ways of accomplishing what you want, and you almost have the rule form correct:

```
Export["test.fits", {"Data" -> data, "Metadata" -> header}, "Rules"]
```

The other ways are

```
Export["test.fits", header, "Metadata"]
Export["test.fits", {data, header}, {{"Data", "Metadata"}}]
```

note the double brackets around the element labels in the second method.

**Edit**: After some testing, due to prodding from @belisarius, whenever I include the "Metadata" element, I get an error stating that it is not a valid export element. Also, you can't export a "RawData" element, either.  So, I'd submit a bug for two reasons: the metadata isn't user settable which is vitally important for any serious application.  At a minimum, the user should at least be able to augment the default Mathematica metadata. Second, the documentation is woefully inadequate in describing what is a "valid" export element vs. import element. Of course, I'd describe all of the documentation for v.6 and beyond as woefully inadequate, so this is par for the course.

Comment: @Markus, I noticed. As I said, the documentation is really very poor.

Comment: @belisarius Only that Export of Metadata is not yet supported and planned for the future. The examples in the documentation refer to the Import functionality. In the meantime i experimented with linking to Pythonika and PyFits to manipulate FITS header. It works but I failed to incorporate this into a usable Package. If you are interested, I can send you the experimental notebook I played around with.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for the offering, but I just wanted to document here the status of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica 9 now allows export of metadata (header) entries, which are additive to the standard required entries.  In the Help browser, search "FITS" and there is an example that shows this (with Export followed by Import to verify).